# Deploying selected microservices in service fabric project

Tags: c#, powershell, deployment, azure-service-fabric

My service fabric application has 9 microservices(stateful and stateless). I need to deploy only specific microservices to service-fabric. Any possible way I can do the same using powershell. I looked into differential packaging but its not the correct way

`app1           2.0.0      <-- new version
     service1     2.0.0      <-- new version
     code       2.0.0      <-- new version
     config     1.0.0
     service2     1.0.0
     code       1.0.0
     config     1.0.0`

Can anyone suggest anything here?

Answer (score 0):

- Deploying the app with elements that have different versions will only replace the changed parts and leave the unchanged elements untouched.
- Alternatively, like you said, you can create a 'diff' package with only the new bits. The result will be the same.
  From the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced#upgrade-with-a-diff-package) where you found the version sample:

> In other words, create a complete application package normally, then
>   remove any code/config/data package folders for which the version has
>   not changed.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-package-apps) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell).

Comment: For diff package, we have to remove the code part and keep config version same. I need to do the same with visual studio without any manual intervention, is there any method for the same?

Comment: VS does that for you by default